# Improve query to select (birth)dates that are within x days from now (future and past)

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table of users with a field `birthday`(DATE).

Currently, I select users who's birthdays is within 7 days past or ahead of the current date like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE 
    DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '1980-%m-%d')
        BETWEEN
        DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 day), '1980-%m-%d')
        AND
        DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 day), '1980-%m-%d')
```

As you can see, this query is not the most streamlined, considering the comparison via the fabricated 1980- date formatting. Also, I believe this will fail to properly select birthday users around the last and first week of the year.

While I am seeing the problems with this, I struggle to find how to approach this. What could I do to improve this query?

Comment: I've updated my comment and made a suitable solution in php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this filter -

```
WHERE
  birthday + INTERVAL EXTRACT(YEAR FROM NOW()) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM birthday) YEAR
  BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Comment: This is elegant and from a quick check I'd say it works. Add the years from now to birthday to the birthday date, then check 7 days back and forth. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$int_range = 7;

$int_start = strtotime("today -{$int_range} Days")
$arr_days = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= ($int_range * 2); $i++)
    $arr_days[] = "'".date('m-d', strtotime("+{$i} Days", $int_start))."'";

$str_days = implode(', ', $arr_days);

mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m-%d') IN ({$str_days})
");
```

Comment: Thanks for your equally good answer. I awarded Devart with the correct answer, because I prefer the mysql-only approach for this particular problem.

Comment: One difference in our queries apart from the php is that Devart's solution will show birthdays the 29th february every year while mine will only each 4th year. I'm not sure which one you prefer. But that's such a little bug it's probably not worth caring about either :)

Comment: Considering the website in question, no :) Thanks for the extra consideration though.